# Get a list of current activities of an application

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-activity

Is there a way that I can check on a specific application which activities are currently running?
To be clear: I am not talking about a check in the code. I am talking about some debug tool that lists the activities in memory currently in a device

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way. I set a `static boolean` for each activity and check for all activities, which are `true`.

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {

     static boolean isActive = false;

      @Override
      public void onStart() {
         //your code
         isActive = true;
      } 

      @Override
      public void onStop() {
         //your code
         active = false;
      }
}
```

Then from where you check, for all activities, just check, if `<Activity>.isActive == true` or not.